# Nonnegative deviation variables in AMPL

Tags: linear-programming, ampl, operations-research

I'm using AMPL and need to input my model that has nonnegative deviation variables (s+ - s-).

An example constraint is:
(x - 5) = (s+ - s-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way to do it:

```
var x;
var sp >= 0;
var sm >= 0;

s.t.

cons1:
  (x - 5) = (sp - sm);
```

FYI, the [AMPL book](http://www.ampl.com/BOOK/download.html) can be downloaded for free.